# Active directory problems with install of Enkompass

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install Enkompass from cPanel to my Winodws 2008 r2 server.
It is in a Active Directory that the program is required to be in, but when I try to install it I get the error

```
"Your system is not a member of an Active Directory domain, or your account does not have privileges on the domain; you must rectify this in order to proceed."
```

So what did I do wrong? I am new to Active Directory, as I am setting up servers for my need, and wanted enkompass on on eserver to handle my website.
Don't blame me for stupidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if your server is not yet joined to the domain.  Here are some instructions on how to accomplish that.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770919(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I have added it to my Active Directory domain, so i'm not sure what is not right, it says something like privilieges, so, i am confused, because computer is on the domain, but still the program says its not in the domain, or doesn't have privilieges.

Comment: Are you logging into the server with a domain user account or a local user? You'll want to use a domain account.